# How to push object synchronously into array

Tags: arrays, angular, asynchronous, angular6

I am fetching data from firestore, and now i want to push data into an empty array in same order of document id provided. When document id is present data should be fetched and pushed into array if no document id is present "No Salesman Assigned" should be pushed into the array.

```
getSalesmanName(signupId){
    let name;
      if(signupId){
        this.db.collection('users/').doc(signupId)
        .snapshotChanges().pipe().map(  res=> {
          const data=res.payload.data() as Users
          return data;
        })
        .subscribe(res=>{
          this.salesmanArray.push(res.first_name);
        })
      }else{
        this.salesmanArray.push("No Salesman Assigned")
      }      
  }
```

Expected Result: Name1, Name2, No Salesman Assigned, Name3, No Salesman Assigned

Actual Result: No Salesman Assigned, No Salesman Assigned, Name1, Name2, Name3

Comment: The `this.db.collection('users/').doc(signupId)` operation is going to run asynchronously. So the control won't wait for the if part of the code to run before running the else part in some cases. Hence the mismatch in the order. Does this result in an error if the `signupId` is undefined and you're still calling `snapshotChanges`?

Comment: Yes, this is what I get.
"Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
getSalesmanName(signupIds) {
  const observableArray = signupIds.map(signupId => {
    if (signupId) {
      return this.db.collection('users/').doc(signupId)
        .valueChanges()
        .pipe(
          map(res => (res as User).first_name)
        )
    } else {
      return of('No Salesman Assigned');
    }
  });

  combineLatest(observableArray)
    .subscribe(res => this.salesmanArray = res);

}
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-firebase-integration-in-lazy-loaded-module?file=src%2Fapp%2Ffire%2Ffire-root%2Ffire-root.component.ts) for your ref.

---

**PS:** I'm assuming that you're using Angular 7.

Comment: Still getting this error!
ERROR FirebaseError: Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: undefined

Comment: @Riyakapoor, I've updated my answer with a working sample stackblitz. Hope that helps.